# Emails stop sending when running vba script which calls and Excel script

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I'm writing a bit of code which is part in Outlook and part in Excel. The first bit of the code in outlook is triggered using a rule based on email address. It then looks in the email and moves the files into a folder on the network drive.

```
Private Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliSeconds As Long)

Public Sub GetFacebookAttachment(itm As Outlook.MailItem)

'set up outlook objects
Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
Dim saveFolder As String
Dim dateFormat As String

Dim xlApp As Object
Dim xlWbk As Object

    'run attachment script
    dateFormat = Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd H-mm")
    saveFolder = "S:\VBA\Recieved"

     For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
          If InStr(objAtt.DisplayName, ".csv") Then
          objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & objAtt.DisplayName
          Set objAtt = Nothing
          End If
     Next

    Sleep 10000
    '    open and run excel script
        Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
            xlApp.Application.Visible = True
            xlApp.Workbooks.Open ("S:\VBA\vba.xlsm")
            xlApp.Application.Run "Module1.Combine_files"

End Sub
```

I've added sleeps to the code as I thought the script might have been to resource heavy however the problem persists.

It then runs the following code (copied from the Microsoft site for combining files but edited to keep the headers):

```
Public Sub Combine_files()

Dim MyPath As String, FilesInPath As String
    Dim MyFiles() As String
    Dim SourceRcount As Long, FNum As Long
    Dim mybook As Workbook, BaseWks As Worksheet
    Dim sourceRange As Range, destrange As Range
    Dim rnum As Long, CalcMode As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim LastColumn As Long
    Dim sourceHeaderRange As Range
    Dim destHeaderRange As Range
    Dim CostCell As Range
    Dim Costrange As Range
    Dim errorCell As Variant

    ' Change this to the path\folder location of your files.
    MyPath = "VBA\Recieved"

    ' Add a slash at the end of the path if needed.
    If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        MyPath = MyPath & "\"
    End If

    ' If there are no Excel files in the folder, exit.
    FilesInPath = Dir(MyPath & "*.csv*")
    If FilesInPath = "" Then
        MsgBox "No files found"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Fill the myFiles array with the list of Excel files
    ' in the search folder.
    FNum = 0
    Do While FilesInPath <> ""
        FNum = FNum + 1
        ReDim Preserve MyFiles(1 To FNum)
        MyFiles(FNum) = FilesInPath
        FilesInPath = Dir()
    Loop

    ' Set various application properties.
    With Application
        CalcMode = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    ' Add a new workbook with one sheet.

    Set BaseWks = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet).Worksheets(1)
    rnum = 2

    ' Loop through all files in the myFiles array.
    If FNum > 0 Then
        For FNum = LBound(MyFiles) To UBound(MyFiles)
            Set mybook = Nothing
            On Error Resume Next
            Set mybook = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & MyFiles(FNum))
            On Error GoTo 0

            If Not mybook Is Nothing Then
                On Error Resume Next

                ' Change this range to fit your own needs.


                With mybook.Worksheets(1)
                    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
                    LastColumn = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
                    Set sourceRange = Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(LastRow, LastColumn))
                    Set sourceHeaderRange = .Rows(1)
                End With

                If Err.Number > 0 Then
                    Err.Clear
                    Set sourceRange = Nothing
                Else
                    ' If source range uses all columns then
                    ' skip this file.
                    If sourceRange.Columns.Count >= BaseWks.Columns.Count Then
                        Set sourceRange = Nothing
                    End If
                End If
                On Error GoTo 0

                If Not sourceRange Is Nothing Then

                    SourceRcount = sourceRange.Rows.Count

                    If rnum + SourceRcount >= BaseWks.Rows.Count Then
                        MsgBox "There are not enough rows in the target worksheet."
                        BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
                        mybook.Close SaveChanges:=False
                        GoTo ExitTheSub
                    Else

                        ' Copy the file name in column A.
                        With sourceRange
                            BaseWks.Cells(rnum, "A"). _
                                    Resize(.Rows.Count).Value = MyFiles(FNum)
                        End With

                        ' Set the destination range.
                        Set destrange = BaseWks.Range("A" & rnum)

                        ' Copy the values from the source range
                        ' to the destination range.
                        With sourceRange
                            Set destrange = destrange. _
                                            Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count)
                        End With

                         Set destHeaderRange = BaseWks.Rows(1)

                        With sourceHeaderRange

                        Set destHeaderRange = destHeaderRange. _
                                            Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count)
                        End With

                        destrange.Value = sourceRange.Value
                        destHeaderRange.Value = sourceHeaderRange.Value
                        rnum = rnum + SourceRcount
                    End If
                End If
                mybook.Close SaveChanges:=False
            End If

        Next FNum
        BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
    End If

ExitTheSub:
    ' Restore the application properties.
    With Application

        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = CalcMode
    End With


SetRate:

'reset lastrow and lastcolumn
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    LastColumn = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
End With



Set CostCell = Cells.Find(what:="Amount Spent (GBP)", MatchCase:=False)

'finds the cell that contains "amount spent (GPB)"


Set Costrange = Range(Cells(2, CostCell.Column), Cells(LastRow, CostCell.Column))

'sets the cost range to equal the amount spent column (excluding the header)

Costrange = Evaluate(Costrange.Address & "*2")

'multipies the values by 1.25


clickTrackers:


With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    'reset lastrow and lastcolumn and copy/paste vlookup
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    LastColumn = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Range("AA1").Value = "Tag"
    Range(Cells(2, LastColumn + 1), Cells(LastRow, LastColumn + 1)).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(LEFT(RC[-23],3)&RC[-22],'clicktags vlookup file]Ad Sheet'!C[-26]:C[-25],2,0)"


End With


CheckForMissingClickTrackers:
'if there are any errors and hence missing click trackers in the lookup the file will still save in the recived
'folder however it will not send and save as a xls for the addional click trackers to be updated.
'save as a csv before sending on.

On Error Resume Next
Set errorCell = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells.SpecialCells(xlFormulas, xlErrors)

If Not errorCell Is Nothing Then GoTo EmailErrorNotification

With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    .SaveAs "S: \VBA\Processed\processedfile_" & Format(Now, "ddmmyyyy") & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV
End With

ActiveWorkbook.Close

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))

SaveAndSend:
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
OutApp.Session.Logon
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
With OutMail
.To = "email@email.com"
.Subject = "RE: did this work?"
.Body = "BOOM! http://gifdanceparty.giphy.com/"
.Attachments.Add ("S: \VBA\Processed\processedfile_" & Format(Now, "ddmmyyyy") & ".Csv")
.SendUsingAccount = OutApp.Session.Accounts.Item(1)
.Send
End With


Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:15"))

GoTo moveFiles

EmailErrorNotification:
Dim OutApp2 As Object
Dim OutMail2 As Object
Set OutApp2 = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
OutApp2.Session.Logon
Set OutMail2 = OutApp2.CreateItem(0)
With OutMail2
.To = "email@email.com"
.Subject = "click trackers missing"
.Body = _
"Hi" _
& vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
"This is an automated email to let you know that todays facebook upload is missing click trackers in the vlookup. Please update the vlookup and send." _
& vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
"Latest file - S:\VBA\Processed" _
& vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
" Vlookup File - S:\clicktags vlookup file.xlsx" _
& vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
" Thanks" _
& vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
"Fane"
.SendUsingAccount = OutApp.Session.Accounts.Item(1)
.Send
End With

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:15"))

With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    .SaveAs "S: \VBA\Processed\processedfile_" & Format(Now, "ddmmyyyy") & ".xlsx"
End With

ActiveWorkbook.Close

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:15"))

moveFiles:

Call move_files

With Application
.DisplayAlerts = False
.ScreenUpdating = True
End With

With Application
.Quit
End With

End Sub


Sub move_files()


Dim objFile As File
Dim objFolder As Folder
Dim objFSO As FileSystemObject
Dim current_path As String
Dim dest_path As String
current_path = "S:\VBA\Recieved"
dest_path = "S:\VBA\OLD"
Set objFSO = New FileSystemObject
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(current_path)

For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
If (objFile.Name <> ThisWorkbook.Name) And (InStr(1, objFile.Name, ".xls") Or InStr(1, objFile.Name, ".csv")) Then
objFile.Move (dest_path & "\" & objFile.Name)
End If

Next objFile





End Sub
```

The previous code calls and opens excel and opens and runs the vba to stack the files together and multiply the cost by a rate.  The file is checked for errors and will either run EmailErrorNotification if there are some or just saveandsend if there are none.

The files are then moved into a folder and the application is closed. this will work when testing each individual sub on it's own but will stop outlook recieving emails and wont run the code as a result of this.  Any help on this would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Don't call `Application.Quit` from within the Excel VBA because Excel was launched/referenced from Outlook. If you want to close Excel when done, use `xlApp.Quit` in the Outlook VBA.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **GetObject** function to return a reference to the Application object that represents a session that is already running. Note that because there can be only one instance of Outlook running at any given time, GetObject usually serves little purpose when used with Outlook. CreateObject can always be used to access the current instance of Outlook or to create a new instance if one does not exist. However, you can use error trapping with the GetObject method to determine whether Outlook is currently running.

Read more about that in the [Automating Outlook from Other Office Applications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869289.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) article.

Also try move the `Quit` method call from Excel's macro to Outlook to close the Excel application.

Did you try to run the GetFacebookAttachment method manually under the debugger?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with debugging, I know how to set breakpoints but what should I look for when running it?

Comment: You may find the [Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) article helpful.

Comment: Thanks, i'll take a look and see if I figure out what's going on.  I've moved the exit to the outlook vba and also swapped the createobject to getobject. I've also tried running this from the combine files sub and the emails seem to send fine, so it must be to do with the outlook code itself.